# Google Calendar's EventQuery not retrieving correct entries

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I am trying to [retrieve](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#RetrievingDateRange) South African public holidays using [Google's .NET Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html).

**I have the following issues:**

1. Some of the retrieved data is outside of the specified `EventQuery` range.  (Both before and after the given date range)
2. Some of the calendar entries are missing. One of them being Christmas 2011-12-25

I verified that this particular public calendar has the correct dates by viewing it [online](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=en.sa%23holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com&ctz=Africa/Johannesburg&gsessionid=OK).

My best guess is that I am using the API incorrectly and that I am querying something like the calendar entry's created/updated date instead of the event date.

***Code:***

```
var feedUrl = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.sa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/full";
var service = new CalendarService("My application name");

var qry       = new EventQuery(feedUrl);
qry.StartDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
qry.EndDate   = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);

EventFeed results = service.Query(qry);

foreach (EventEntry entry in results.Entries)
{
    if (entry.Times.Count == 0)  
       continue;

    // Using entry.Times[0].StartTime results in 
    // missing data and data outside of the given search criteria.
}
```

I am using the latest available [Google .NET Data API 1.7.0.1](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/detail?name=Google%20Data%20API%20Setup%20%281.7.0.1%29.msi&can=2&q=)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue:

```
qry.StartDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
qry.EndDate   = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
```

should be:

```
qry.StartTime = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
qry.EndTime   = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
```

This solves both of my issues mentioned in my question.  (Not sure why the `EventQuery` class has both Date/Time properties, this is confusing when only the one set works).